# How to produce an arbitary string with a specific length in python?

Tags: python, string

I need to have a 100000 characters long  string. What is the most efficient and shortest way of producing such a string in python?
The content of the string is not of importance.

Comment: Why do you need this? If you modify it in any way, a new string will be created.

Comment: *"what is the shortest way"* ... shortest in terms of code golf, or most efficient?

Comment: @eumiro I need this string to do some testing in a script I've written.

Comment: @ShawnChin In this case efficiency has higher priority.

Comment: @EdwinDrood In that case, it might be worth stating that in the question. Shortest != efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
'x' * 100000 # or,

''.join('x' for x in xrange(100000)) # or,

from itertools import repeat
''.join(repeat('x', times=100000))
```

Or for a bit of a mixup of letters:

```
from string import ascii_letters
from random import choice
''.join(choice(ascii_letters) for _ in xrange(100000))
```

Or, for some random data:

```
import os
s = os.urandom(100000)
```

Comment: @EdwinDrood note that `'a'*100000` is faster than `"abcd"*2500`. See benchmark in my answer (community wiki).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

```
s = 'a' * 100000
```

Answer (score 2):

Since efficiency is important, here's a quick benchmark for some of the approaches mentioned so far:

```
$ python -m timeit "" "'a'*100000"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.99 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "from itertools import repeat" "''.join(repeat('x', times=100000))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.24 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit "import array" "array.array('c',[' ']*100000).tostring()"
100 loops, best of 3: 3.92 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit "" "''.join('x' for x in xrange(100000))"
100 loops, best of 3: 5.69 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit "import os" "os.urandom(100000)"
100 loops, best of 3: 6.17 msec per loop
```

Not surprisingly, of the ones posted, using string multiplication is the fastest by far.

Also note that it is more efficient to multiply a single char than a multi-char string (to get the same final string length).

```
$ python -m timeit "" "'a'*100000"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.99 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "" "'ab'*50000"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.02 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "" "'abcd'*25000"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "" "'abcdefghij'*10000"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.03 usec per loop
```

Tested on Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 1):

Strings can use the multiplication operator:

```
"a" * 100000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making an array of blank characters.

```
import array
longCharArray = array.array('c',[' ']*100000)
```

This will allocate an array of `' '` characters of size 100000

```
longCharArray.tostring()
```

Will convert to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick some character and repeat it 100000 times:

```
 "a"*100000
```

Why you would want this is another question. . .

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
"".join(random.sample(string.lowercase * 385,10000))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one liner:

```
''.join([chr(random.randint(32, 126)) for x in range(30)])
```

Change the range() value to get a different length of string; change the bounds of randint() to get a different set of characters.